How to access an instance variable in another class in python
I am writing a program that is utilizing multiple classes. I have one class that is dedicated to determining values for a set of variables and a py file have an instance of class login. I would then like to be able to access the values of those variables with other classes. My code looks as follows:
main.py:
import login
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    login.Login(root)


login.py:
import admin

class Login:
    def __init__(self , root):
        self.root = root
        self.var1= tk.StringVar()
            

    def loginFunc(self):
        self.var3= tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.var1) #var1 get value through tkinter form
        admin.AdminControls(self.root)



admin.py:
import login

class AdminControls:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.adminControlsFrame()

    def adminControlsFrame(self):
        self.labelName= Label(self.entriesFrame, text="welcome"+var1) #this is where I want to use var1



I have 7 variables in login class just as same as var1 and I need to use them all in admin.
should I just pass them all as function arguments (like admin.AdminControls(self.root, var1, var2, var3, ..)) or is there a cleaner way?
I have read Use or access class instances directly in another class in Python, but the problem is my classes are in different files.

In my opinion, it depends on whether it makes sense conceptually for AdminControls to have a reference to Login; which might very well make it. In that case, then you'd be fine passing the Login instance to AdminControls. What kind of variables are those?

Edit: I wasn't aware of passing variables from login to admin.
Edit: Those two instances of class login and admin had changed.

I have one class that is dedicated to determining values for a set of
variables and a py file have an instance of class login. I would then
like to be able to access the values of those variables with other
classes

The problem can be fixed:
Every tkinter widget must have a layout manager such as place(), pack() and grid(). So, we can see GUI graphics.
Every module must include a namespace, such as import tkinter as tk. And we can write root = tk.Tk() for every module.
There are some minor changes.
In login.py, Add the tk.StringVar.set()
In admin.py and login.py. We must use self.root window for Label and Entry widget instead of self
In admin.py, Add the Label widget in the construction class. So we can use .configure to update the Login Entry widget.
Also, every Tkinter widget must have a layout. So, we can use pack() to suit your needs.
Lastly, in main.py, we can create a function called login.py module.
Snippet:
main.py:
import login
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def main():
    root.destroy() 
    login.Login(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

In login.py:
import admin
import tkinter as tk

 
root = tk.Tk()
class Login:
    def __init__(self , root):
        self.root = root
        self.var1= tk.StringVar()
        self.var1.set('Reyhan d')
            

    def loginFunc(self):
        self.var3 = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.var1) #var1 get value through tkinter form
         
        admin.AdminControls(self.root, self.var3.get())
        self.var3.pack(pady=50)

 
app = Login(root)
app.loginFunc()

admin.py:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class AdminControls():
    def __init__(self, root, data):
        self.root = root
        self.data = data
        self.labelName = tk.Label(self.root) #this is where I want to use var1
        self.labelName.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.adminControlsFrame()

    def adminControlsFrame(self):
        #self.labelName = tk.Label(self.root, text="welcome") #this is where I want to use var1
        #self.labelName.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.labelName.configure(text=f"welcome {self.data}")
        
root.destroy()

Noted: If you want on fly, then you can bind 
I will add it later when I get home.
Screenshot:


I had a typo , va1   is actully var1 , and I want to use its value in  class admin

thank you for your explanation, so the only way I can access the variable is passing it as function argument.

I got another one working. You can type Entry, and it will update Label widget. But cannot destroy Label widget. I will not post answer.
